# I want to paginate my select query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem with a query when I use pagination with select in Laravel. However, I found some Laravel Eloquent code but the problem is that it also doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```php
public function categoryall($urlid)
{
    // Old query
    // $procat = DB::select('select * from products where category_id in 
    // (select id from categories where parent_id = ?)', [$urlid]);

    $procat = Product::whereIn('category_id', function ($query) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from(with(new Category)->getTable())
            ->where('parent_id', [$urlid]);
    })->paginate(5);

    return view('products.category')->with(compact('procat'));
}
```

Comment: What is not working? What results do you get and what do you expect to get? Are there any error messages?

Comment: yes eror is  ( Undefined variable: urlid)

Comment: You probably have to pass the `$urlid` variable through the route. What is the route that calls this controller method?

Comment: `function ($query) use ($urlid) {`

Comment: Can you provide the code used for your route?

Comment: Route::get('/category/{urlid}','ProductsController@categoryall');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it like this `function ($query) use ($urlid)`
and `where('urlid',$urlid)`
If you want it `whereIn` put it as array

Answer (score 1):

Because relation of categories and products table is ManyMany, so build a pivot table category_product like:

```
    Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Then, set some relationships and datas on 3 tables, and  use below function to paginate:

```
public function categoryall($urlid)
{
    $category_ids = Category::where('parent_id',$urlid)->pluck('id'); // = [1,2]
    $products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category_ids) {
        $query->whereIn('category_id', $category_ids);
    })->paginate(5);
    return $products;
}
```

And ask me, if you need!

Comment: thanks for your answer. but the problem is I am using Database first approach... so how can I create this relationship?

Comment: You can reference the tut in this link: https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: Or this: https://appdividend.com/2018/05/17/laravel-many-to-many-relationship-example/

Comment: Your pleasure also is my pleasure! Keep go on!